# React-Native this prop randomNumberCount is marked as required in Game ,but its value undefined

Tags: react-native

**Game.js**

```
    import React from 'react';
    import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
    import {View,Text,StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
```

And this is my code and this is the warning `this prop randomNumberCount  is marked as required in Game ,but its value undefined`. How to solve this warning?

```
class Game extends React.Component {
        static propTypes = {
            randomNumberCount: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
        };
        randomNumbers=Array
        .from({length:this.props.randomNumberCount})
        .map(() =>1+Math.floor(10*Math.random()));
        target=this.randomNumbers
        .slice(0,this.props.randomNumberCount-2)
        .reduce((acc,curr)=>acc+curr,0);

      render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text  style={styles.target}>{this.target}</Text>
          {this.randomNumbers.map((randomNumber,index)=>
            <Text key={index}>{randomNumber}</Text>


            )}

          </View>
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: The error how to solve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This warning is because you have marked **randomNumberCount** as required in prototype. So when you use this component, you need to compulsory pass the prop *randomNumberCount*. Or you can remove the ***.isRequired*** from prototype declaration.

You can declare default value for *randomNumberCount* as

```
static defaultProps = {
    randomNumberCount: dafaultValue
};
```

For reference: 
[Native Component](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-components-ios.html)

Comment: the warning is gone but random number keep giving me 0 as a random number

Comment: Did you passed 'randomNumberCount' prop to 'Game' component from parent component?